# Display pdf files with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to display PDF files with ng-repeat and I am getting the following error:

> HTTP Error 404.0

If I display a single pdf everything works fine. `{{pdfFile.url}}` is printing:

```
~/Content/PdfFiles/Test1.pdf 
~/Content/PdfFiles/Test2.pdf
```

```
<div>
    @*<iframe src="~/Content/PdfFiles/Test1.pdf" style="width:100%; height:600px;" type='application/pdf'></iframe>*@
    <div ng-repeat="pdfFile in pdfFiles">
        {{pdfFile.url}}
        <iframe src="{{pdfFile.url}}" style="width:100%; height:600px;" type='application/pdf'></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It won't work with ~/path be explicit about the path. If your folder is root/content/PdfFiles/Test1.pdf either give the absolute path or the relative path (i.e. if the page containing your example code is one level below Content : '/Content/PdfFiles/Test1.pdf'). I take it you are using .net and getting routes back with ~. those are typically interpreted by the view engine to render proper URLs They are not understood or interpreted by angular and are invalid hence 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with ng-src:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{pdfFile.url}}" style="width:100%; height:600px;" type='application/pdf'></iframe>
```

Hope it helps =)

Edit:  Added {{}} notation for the ng-src attribute inside the iframe tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

**controller :**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.pdfFiles = [
    {
    "url": "http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf"
    },
    {
    "url": "http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf"
    }
    ];
});
```

**View :**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="pdfFile in pdfFiles">
        {{pdfFile.url}}
        <iframe src="{{pdfFile.url}}" style="width:100%; height:300px;" type='application/pdf'></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

## [Working demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/13200/)